# vb.net SQL connection string, writing only last value in database

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

Probably a very easy question, but i am having some problems with it.
Currently I am extracting data from OLAP Sever and writing it to SQL Database. I created my database with the below string.

```
   Dim strSQL As String =
            "CREATE TABLE Datab(" &
            "ID Int IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY," &
            "No Int NOT NULL," &
            "Name NVarChar(40) NOT NULL," &
            "basicvalue NVarChar(40) NOT NULL," &
            "Datee Date NOT NULL," &
           ")"
```

My connection is as follows:
            Dim dbConnection As New SqlConnection(connectionString)

```
        'A SqlCommand object is used to execute the SQL commands.
        Dim cmd As New SqlCommand(strSQL, dbConnection)
        Dim regDate As DateTime = DateTime.Now
        Dim strDate As String = regDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")

        If IsError(mdsRet) = vbTrue Then
            MsgBox("Error Connecting: " & IsError(MdsGetLastError))
        Else
            '  MsgBox("Connected to Server: " + mdsRet)

            'Check the number of Cubes in OLAP
            If tables.TablesCount(srv) >= 0 Then

                dbConnection.Open()
                'Counter from 1 to nu. of Cubes
                cmd1.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text
                For counter As Integer = 1 To tables.TablesCount(srv)
                    cmd1.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Datab(No, Name, basicvalue,datee) VALUES ('" & counter & "','" + tables.TablesName(srv, counter) + "','" & tables.TableGetInfo(srv, tables.TablesName(srv, counter), 56) & "','" & strDate & "')"


                    cmd1.Connection = dbConnection
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
                    cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery()
                    counter = counter + 1
                Next

            End If

        End If

        'close DB connection
        dbConnection.Close()
```

The connection writes the line into database, but not incrementing the index Row and so I am getting the last value in database table i.e. after execution is finished.. 
in total there are about 60 rows to be written.

I tried different options to increment the counter, but its not working. Can anyone help and explain.

Thank you

Comment: Remove `counter = counter + 1` as the For loop will auto increment `counter`. Not sure of the structure of `tables.TablesName(srv, counter)` however these normally start at 0. So change `For counter As Integer = 1` to `For counter As Integer = 0` and when you insert here `('" & counter & "','"` just change that to `('" & (counter + 1) & "','"`. You will also want to look into `Parameters` rather than concatenating a string together.

Comment: hi @Jinx88909, i did change it.. if i change `For counter As Integer = 0` then i get an SQL conversion error from String to Double and when i insert `('" & (counter + 1) & "','"` then its simply incrementing the counter i.e. when counter it should be 1 it writes 2 ( 1+1).

Comment: Yeah you need to start at 0 for that last bit to work. I'm assuming `tables.TablesName` is zero based meaning the first records start at 0 not 1? The error will be something else and it might help to address that by using parameters. so `cmd1.Parameters.Add()`. Turning on **Option Strict** will also help with coding in the long run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, such a fool of me.. 
At every execution it was executing the create query that means it was deleting the table and creating new.

I deleted the row `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()` from the loop and added it before the loop execution. It worked perfectly.

Although thanks @Jinx88909

Comment: You know what, I missed the top of the question and thought the other cmd was just you testing  :) glad you've sorted it though.